# How to Authorize different login Url in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I have two login but how can I assign these login URLs with using authorize ?

Here is my webconfig :

```
 <location path="Home">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>  
  </location>


 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

So how can I create second loginurl ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have 2 logon urls in Forms Authentication. If you need to achieve this functionality you could write custom `[Authorize]` attributes and then override the [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method where you could redirect to the corresponding logon url.

For example:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string _controller;
    private readonly string _action;
    public MyAuthorizeAttribute(): this("account", "logon")
    {
    }

    public MyAuthorizeAttribute(string controller, string action)
    {
        _controller = controller;
        _action = action;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            controller = _controller,
            action = _action,
            returnurl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
        });
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class SomeController
{
    [MyAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [MyAuthorize("account", "someotherlogonaction")]
    public ActionResult Bar()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```